# Remove Menu Button from Title Bar in KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg-g2, menu

I have a Verizon LG G2, which I just updated to Android 4.4 KitKat. The G2 already has the menu button in its bottom navigation bar, but the 4.4 update, as expected, put an extra menu button in the top right corner of most apps.

I find this unnecessary, and it just takes up space and messes up my workflow. Is there any way I could remove the top menu button, either through settings or a 3rd-Party App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, there is no way to remove the "Menu" overflow button from within apps in 4.4, even on phones with a hardware Menu button.  This was an intentional change by Google in KitKat to unify the interface across devices.

It's possible to remove this overflow button with some OS modifications, and many custom ROMs do offer a toggle for this.  However, it requires rooting the device, unlocking its bootloader, and installing a 3rd-party modified OS.